# Calling an applet from html

Tags: java, html, netbeans, applet

I am working on a project and need to call an applet from HTML, im doing this:

```
<applet code="AppletClient.class" width="350" height="200" </applet>
```

It's giving me an error that the `AppletClient.class` cannot be found. If I copy that file and paste it in the same location of the HTML file it works. How can I fix this?

Comment: `<applet code="AppletClient.class" width="350" height="200" </applet>` is not only invalid, but malformed.  I recommend 1) to validate the HTML using a [validation service](http://validator.w3.org/) 2) Load the validated HTML using [Appleteer](http://pscode.org/appleteer/) (designed to give more and better feed-back on applet loading). 3) Once you get a working example, use `deployJava.js` in production (to write the applet element).

Answer (score 3):

> " however if i copy that file and paste it in the same location of the
>   html file it works no problem "

You have already noticed the issue. Correct the path, it will work. Right now you are navigating to the classess folder. However, try removing the first "/".

```
<applet code="AppletClient.class" codebase="/classes"

            width="350" height="200">
```

put location inside the codebase tag. Code tag is for the class name. I missed it first time , sorry :(

Comment: still doesnt work, in the code i pasted above it had to be code="AppletClient.class", with that it was working when i paste it, but in any way i try change the path it doesnt seem to be working :S

Comment: OK, is there a folder called "classes" ? Is your applet file is inside that?

Comment: yes to be more specific its in NetBeansProjects\WebApplication1\build\web\WEB-INF\classes

Comment: It is inside the "web" folder right? If yes, give the path like "\WEB-INF\classes\AppletClient.class"

If it didn't work, "WEB-INF\classes\AppletClient.class"

Comment: ive tried and still does not work, i cant understand what im doing wrong

Comment: shall we do a small test? Take both class and HTML into a separate folder like "MyApp" which is outside the netbeans projects. Create a folder "classes" inside the folder "MyApp" and copy the class to there. Keep the HTML inside the "MyApp". Change the path in HTML to "classes/AppletClient.class". Run the HTML. If this works, then definitely there is a problem in the way you gave the path in netbeans case

Comment: did the same thing where i put them in same directory and works fine

Comment: still no luck :( i might just copy paste it since nothing seems to be working

Comment: Now OK? Else, refer the following

http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/applets/_APPLET_CODE.html

Comment: still not working, did code="AppletClient.class" codebase="../classes/"

Comment: WAIT it worked on the test now because i gave it the whole path in codebase including c:// etc, ill try it in netbeanst

Comment: OK. Giving the complete path is not a good idea anyway. However, I am waiting, reply if it worked

Comment: with the complete path in netbeans it just loads a blank page, witth the web-inf part it doesnt work hmmm

Comment: There is another thing you should know. Normally Netbeans webApp categories are used to create web apps with JSP, Servlet, etc. In your case, it is not needed actually. However, pardon me I couldn't help you 100%. However, I am glad to help you at least for 50% :)

Comment: You are almost welcome :) Just find out the correct path ( I mean the way of giving it inside codebase). Thats all :)